# how to solve error in mysql_real_escape_string() function?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\register.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\register.php on line 19

```
   <?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    echo "Username entered is : ". $username . "<br/>";
    echo "Password entered is : ". $password;
}
?>
```

Here in line 19 the following code lies:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

---

Then I tried using mysqli().so i changed my php code like this:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    echo "Username entered is : ". $username . "<br/>";
    echo "Password entered is : ". $password;
}
?>
```

[Then it shows this output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hT7o.png)

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\register.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyFirstWebsite\register.php on line 20

Here, on line 19 and line 20 .The following code lies:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what should be in that code?

Comment: with the code using `mysqli_` it's telling you what the problem and googling the function name the very first result [is the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) showing you can't just stick an i in the function name and expect it to work

Comment: You should pass link identifier as first parameter, see it on PHP Manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass connection variable as first argument like below:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
```

Here `$conn` is

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','dbname');
```